# appdynamics_javaprocess alert whenever the process goes down

Tags: centos, appdynamics

I am looking to setup a monitoring alert in AppDynamics. I want to generate an email alert whenever the java process in the Centos machine goes down. How do i set this up?  I am using AppD version 4.2. I have tried installing the process monitoring plugin, but I am still not getting any data in custom metrics.

https://www.appdynamics.com/community/exchange/extension/process-monitoring-extension/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a machine agent extension (and additional custom metrics) to capture if a JVM goes down. The machine agent delivers these kind of information out of the box. You have to start the java process with the app server agent and associate the application, that is instrumented with the machine agent. Now you can go to the `application dashboard -> Events tab` and check for the `JVM Crash Event`. See also [here](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Monitor+JVMs) and [here](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/JVM+Crash+Guard).